# Problem in understanding wildcard capturing

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism

I have following code inspect:

```
List<? extends Number> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // Line 1  
int a = nums.get(0); // Line 2 - cannot convert from capture#1-of ? extends Number to int
```

Polymorphically, I can understand why it makes sense to for line 2 to generate error.     This is because nums may contain list of any child of Number (Long,Integer etc) so its only allowed to assign to Parent type (Number).
From perspective of wildcard capturing, I am facing difficulty to make sense of it. As I understand, #CAP1 of "? extends Number" is Integer so i should be able to do line 2.
Could someone please help me explain the behavior in terms of wildcard capturing.

Regards,
Tarun

Comment: *As I understand, #CAP1 of "? extends Number" is Integer*. Why do you say that?

Comment: @shmosel Because I am assigning new ArrayList<Integer>() to nums in the first line.

Comment: That's lost to the compiler as soon as you assign it. It's like assigning an `Integer` to a `Number` variable.

Comment: @shmosel You are saying at Line 2, Compile dont know what is #CAP1, All it knows is nums contains data of Number or its subtypes. But dont know which exact subtype it is.

Comment: That's correct.